# Achartengine: toScreenPoint result is off

Tags: android, charts, data-visualization, achartengine

I'm adding a touch slider on a graph chart, using toRealpoint and toScreenpoint to convert coordinate system. It worked fine if the the Renderer.setXAxisMin and Renderer.setXAxisMax are set to the first and last points in the data collection.

But if I set min and max to other value to get some zoom in and out effects, the slider position will be off. I called GraphicalView.repaint(). Is this an achartengine bug or do I need to do something to update the internal properties? Thanks

The slider lies correctly on the data point:
[image: Correct]

The slider is off, after I changed XAxisMin and XAxisMax:
[image: Wrong]

This is a TimeChart.

Comment: I think this is an achartengine bug.

Comment: What is the slider? Is it another series that is displayed using a different scale? Some code could help.